# Do we need a visa to Germany

Tags: schengen-visas, dual-nationality, ryanair

I’m travelling to Germany next week with my partner and daughter, when booking the flights I put my husbands nationality as Turkish not realising it should have been British as he is a British citizen now. He has to go to visa check before he gets his boarding pass,we don’t have a visa for him and won’t get one in time for our holiday. does he need a visa for Germany even though he holds a British passport and is a citizen here?

Comment: Inform RyanAir that he is a British citizen and will be travelling with a British passport. If they "can't" change that entry, show the British passport at checkin. As long as he enters with a British passport, no visa is required.

Comment: Thank you, I’ve already printed the boarding passes, I will try and phone them and see if they will change nationality for me

Answer (score 3):

As a dual citizen you can choose which passport to travel on. For most airlines it's no problem to change a passport after booking and/or at check-in as long as the name is the same.

To be safe, you should confirm with the airline directly

Comment: I was worried as I put his nationality as Turkish but put his British passport details in

Comment: @Chelsea the agent at the visa check will recognize that he does not need a visa because he has a British passport.  Since Ryanair's business model seems to revolve around charging passengers for every little thing, you should be prepared for the possibility that they consider this a change to the booking for which a fee must be paid (most airlines would not, however, so maybe they won't either).  Regardless, there should be no trouble actually boarding the flight.

Comment: Thank you! I did phone and told them I made a mistake but he said all details were correct to be honest I don’t think he understood my questions